# There is an error in the below mentioned line- ParserError: Expected identifier but got '(' receive() external payable^

Tags: blockchain, solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0; 
contract Lottery 
{
address public manager;
address payable[] participants;

constructor() public
{
manager = msg.sender;
}
receive() external payable   //error on this line
{
require(msg.value==1 ether);
participants.push(payable(msg.sender));
}

function getBalance() public view returns(uint)
{
require(msg.sender==manager);
return address(this).balance;

}
function randomG() public view returns(uint)
{
return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, participants.length)));
}

function SelectWinner() public 
{
uint r=randomG();
uint index= r % participants.length; 
address payable winner;
winner = participants[index];
winner.transfer(getBalance());

}
}
```

Please identify what is the error with the recieve function.This is a smart contract for a lottery system where a random winner is selected and paid. I cannot receive ether from the participant's address. what is wrong with the function? Are there any alternatives for the same?

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

In remix, compiler 0.8.18. Your contract code can accept transfers from other accounts, and only 1 ether will be executed successfully.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why only 1 ether? Please explain.

Comment: `require(msg.value==1 ether);`If msg.value is not equal to 1ether it will revert.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the participants array was not initialized in the constructor. To solve this issue, add the following line in the constructor:

```
participants = new address payable[](0);
```

This will initialize the participants array as an empty array.

Comment: I am still getting the error, even after initialising the array.

Comment: I tested with Solidity 0.8.17 using Hardhat. Can you try with the same?